# Datetime formats are inconsistent between DateTime.ToString and DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

this is very curious. When I run, for example,

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Result is

```
"22-02-2022"
```

Notice that I requested a slash separator, not hyphen separator. However, I guess this is a control panel definition although I think it shouldn't.

Well.... now, I try to do the contrary, converting a string to a date, so I used this,

```
DateTime.ParseExact("22-02-2022", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

After that, a `FormatException` is thrown.

To be consistent, I think if for the system, a hyphen is the separator, when converting in both directions, that separator should be the same, shouldn't it?

Of course, if I use,

```
DateTime.ParseExact("22/02/2022", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

It works.

As a workaround, I replace hyphens by slashes before converting string to date, but that is only an ugly workaround. Is there a way to make the system be consistent?

Jaime

Comment: For me, the `.ToString` call results in the expected result with slashes instead of hyphens.  What is your current culture, and what happens if you use the invariant culture?

Comment: What happens if you pass `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` into the `ToString` call as well?

Comment: `CurrentUICulture` can be different from `CurrentCulture`. The latter is used if no format provider is given. The character `/` is a symbol that depends on the format provider. You must escape or quote it if you want it to mean a literal slash, just like you must escape or quote a `d` if you want it to mean the literal letter d and not the date component.

Comment: To see if this is really inconsistent, we must know what `CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` and `CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` are, as @JonSkeet is hinting at. Can you tell us that? Also, can you tell if `DateTime.ParseExact("22-02-2022", "dd/MM/yyyy", null)` passes?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann It reproduces if you do `var c = (CultureInfo)(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone()); c.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-"; CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = c;` first. The date separator of the current culture depends on the locale of the machine on which the program runs, if not otherwise given.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're seeing that issue because the region/localization settings of the machine doesn't use `/` as a date separator.

The docs on [the "/" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) says:

> To change the date separator for a particular date and time string,
> **specify the separator character within a literal string delimiter**. For
> example, the custom format string `mm'/'dd'/'yyyy` produces a result
> string in which "/" is always used as the date separator.

And then:

> If the "/" format specifier is used without other custom format
> specifiers, it's interpreted as a standard date and time format
> specifier and throws a `FormatException`.

You have a couple of options to output the desired separator:

1. Wrap the date separator in apostrophes:

   ```
   DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
   ```
2. Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when calling `ToString`:

   ```
   DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   ```

Both of these should produce a date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` using "/" for the separator.

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jATbbK)